# Spring boot JPA related entity clarification

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have an entity like Process, which will be created by , updated by one user. When I try to apply the filter. I have created the foreign key relationship in the database. Now, when I use the JPA Specification to apply dynamic filter, I am getting exception as

`No property CREATED found for type Process!`

```
@Table(name = "process")
@Entity
public class Process {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "PROCESS_ID")
    @JsonProperty("id")
    private Long id = null;
    
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "NAME")
    @JsonProperty("name")
    private String name = null;

    @Column(name = "CREATED_BY", updatable = false)
    @JsonProperty("createdBy")
    private Long createdBy = null;

    @Column(name = "updatedBy", nullable = true)
    @JsonProperty("updatedBy")
    private Long updatedBy = null;
}
```

Hence, I Added the entity relationship mapping in the process entity as given below,

Now, I am getting below error. I am new to JPA and hibernate, the relation mapping is very confusing, kindly help.

```
@Table(name = "process")
@Entity
public class Process {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "PROCESS_ID")
    @JsonProperty("id")
    private Long id = null;
    
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "NAME")
    @JsonProperty("name")
    private String name = null;

    @Column(name = "CREATED_BY", updatable = false)
    @JsonProperty("createdBy")
    private Long createdBy = null;

    @Column(name = "updatedBy", nullable = true)
    @JsonProperty("updatedBy")
    private Long updatedBy = null;
    
    //newly added below properties so that there will be no error when fetching data
     @OneToOne(targetEntity = UserDetails.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "id")
    private UserDetails CREATED;

    @OneToOne(targetEntity = UserDetails.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "id")
    private UserDetails UPDATED;

}
```

Now, I am getting the below error
`Referenced property not a (One|Many)ToOne: com.app.users.details.domain.UserDetails.id in mappedBy of com.app.scenarios.domain.Process.CREATED`

Kindly let me know what i am doing wrong. I have a process which can be created by a user and can be updated by a user. In DB, I am having a foreign key relationship for process and userdetails entity.

**EDIT**

Code to get the filtered data from DB using JPA Specification

`Page<process> result = this.processDao.findAll(getprocessGridData(processSearchCondition.getprocessName()), pageRequest);`

```
  private static Specification<process> getprocessGridData(String processName) {
        return (Specification<process>) (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> (
                criteriaBuilder.like(root.get("name"), processName)
        );
    }
```

Comment: `when I use the JPA Specification to apply dynamic filter` - Please show how exactly did you do it?

Comment: added the code using the jpa specification that was used. Due to the above relationshop error, the application is not running

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you actually want is this:

```
@Table(name = "process")
@Entity
public class Process {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "PROCESS_ID")
    @JsonProperty("id")
    private Long id;
    
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "NAME")
    @JsonProperty("name")
    private String name;
    
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @jOINColumn(name = "CREATED_BY", updatable = false)
    private UserDetails createdBy;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "UPDATED_BY", nullable = true)
    private UserDetails updatedBy;

}
```